# Laptop keyboard doesn't work after suspension/hibernation

Tags: systemd, keyboard, suspend, hibernate

On my Ubuntu 20.04 (problem persists since 16.04) Sony VAIO laptop if I close the lid, wait till the yellow led to blink and then turn the laptop on again, awakes everything but keyboard, which turns on it's backlight after first keypress but doesn't react to anything, so does the touchpad. So I get almost fully working system, but completely unusuable.
My problem is that I don't even know where to search for problem origin. I don't know how the laptop power and keyboard management works in Ubuntu, not on systemd or SysV level, nor on kernel level. So, no logs for you, my friends, until you ask for any. =)
How can I solve this very annoying issue please?

Comment: maybe helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/916465/ubuntu-17-04-keyboard-not-responding-after-suspend

Answer (score 0):

Re-install "xserver-xorg-input-kbd" from package manager -- and possibly other xorg-input-devices that got messed up from your latest kernel update!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is related to [Bug 195471](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195471). 
It's a bug that has been present in the Linux kernel since a few years ago.

I have a VAIO laptop too, and it's affected with that bug. 
I have found two workarounds:

1. After resume **to not** press any key but <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, wait a couple of seconds until the Caps Lock LED turns on, and then the keyboard works normally.
2. If you're willing to compile the module yourself, take a look [to this patched kernel module](https://github.com/Tedyst/i8042-SonyLaptop/), it even includes a systemd service unit that automatically restarts the driver after resume, so this is more like a fix than a workaround, but I doubt it would be merged to upstream kernels as it seems that the models affected are not that many.

Hope this helps!